# uniformly convergent series for holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f\in H(B(0,1))$, $f(0)=0$. Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |f(z^n)| $uniformly converge on an arbitrary compact set $K\subset B(0,1)$.

---

$f$ can be expanded to Taylor series at $0$, i.e. $f=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k$. So $f(z^n)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^{kn}$. So $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |f(z^n)|=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^{kn}$. Then I am stuck how to prove the convergence of this series?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is holomorphic on $B(0,1)$ with $f(0)=0 $ so let $M=1+|f'(0)|$ and take $r\in (0,1)$ such that $$\forall z\in B(0,r)\;(|f(z)|\leq M |z|).$$ For compact $K\subset B(0,1)$ take  $s\in (0,1)$ with $K\subset B(0,s).$

Given $\epsilon >0,$ take $n_0$ such that $s^{n_0}<\min (\epsilon,r) .$ Then  for all $n\geq n_0$ and all $z\in K$ we have $$\left|\sum_{j=n}^{n+m}f(z^j)\right|\leq \sum_{j=n}^{n+m}|f(z^j)|\leq \sum_{j=n}^{n+m}M |z|^j=$$ $$=M|z|^n\cdot \frac {1-|z|^{m+1}}{1-|z|}\leq M |z|^n\cdot\frac {1}{1-s}\leq$$ $$\leq  M s^n \cdot \frac {1}{1-s}\leq  M s^{n_0}\cdot \frac {1}{1-s}\leq\frac {M}{1-s} \epsilon.$$

Comment: Sorry but I do not find it explicit to understand why such an $r$ exists? Why you can get $|f(z)|\leq 2M|z|$?

Comment: For $0\ne z\in B(0,1)$ we have $f(z)/z=(f(z)-f(0)/(z-0)=f'(0)+g(z)$ where  $\lim_{z\to 0}g(z)=0.$  So there exists $r\in (0,1)$ such that  $0<|z|<r\implies$ $ |g(z)|<1\implies$ $ |f(z)|=|z|(f'(0)+g(z)|\leq$ $ |z|(|f'(0)|+|g(z)|)\leq$ $ |z|(|f'(0)|+1)=|z|M.$ .... Now I see that I could have written $|f(z)|\leq M|z|$ instead, which is sharper.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Your solution is perfect.